# Add item to SharePoint 2010 list through MATLAB

Tags: web-services, matlab, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

Is it possible to add an item to a list in SharePoint 2010 through MATLAB? I assume there must be some .NET web services that could help me but my .NET knowledge is limited so any guidance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used MATLAB before, but from the documentation it looks like you can create a MATLAB class by targeting the wsdl of SharePoint's "Lists" web service. You can use the following URL to access the wsdl, replacing  with the SharePoint site that contains the list you need to alter.

http:///_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Lists(v=office.12).aspx
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/accessing-web-services-that-use-wsdl-documents.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it appears to be exactly what I was after.